# stringr::str_sub output is unexpected

Tags: r, string, stringr, stringi

Consider the folowing data.frame:

```
df <- structure(list(sufix = c("atizado", "atoria", "atório", "auta", 
                         "áutico", "ável"), min_stem_len = c(4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 2), replacement = c("", 
                                                                                                "", "", "", "", ""), exceptions = list(character(0), character(0), 
                                                                                                                                       character(0), character(0), character(0), c("afável", "razoável", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "potável", "vulnerável"))), .Names = c("sufix", "min_stem_len", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "replacement", "exceptions"), row.names = 21:26, class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have a list of strings in variable `sufix` of this data.frame.
Now I have a word `word <- "amável"` and I want to get the sufix of this word with the same length as each word of the `df$sufix`.

I'm using the folowing code:

```
library(stringr)
word <- "amável"
str_sub(word, start = -stringr::str_length(df$sufix))
```

But this outputs this:

```
> str_sub(word, start = -stringr::str_length(df$sufix))
[1] "amável" "mável"  "mável"  "vel"    "mável"  "vel"   
> df$sufix
[1] "atizado" "atoria"  "atório"  "auta"    "áutico"  "ável"
```

I was expecting that the last element of the resulting vector to be "ável" since:

```
> str_length("ável")
[1] 4
> str_sub(word, start = -4)
[1] "ável"
```

---

Here a more simple reproducible example:

```
set.seed(100)
a <- sample(1:10, 10000, replace = T)
res <- rep("ábc", 10000) %>% str_sub(start = -a)
sum(ifelse(a > 3, 3, a) != str_length(res))
[1] 2504
```

Comment: raised an issue to stringi's github page: https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/issues/227

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the development branch of `stringi`, see https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/issues/227 (as `str_sub` from `stringr` relies upon `stri_sub` in `stringi`). Once an update is available on CRAN, the correct behavior shall be replicable by anyone from the "general public", than is:

```
str_sub(word, start = -stringr::str_length(df$sufix))
## [1] "amável" "amável" "amável" "ável"   "amável" "ável"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you notice, all the results are wrong (except by the first one).

They should have been

```
[1] "amável" "amável" "amável" "ável"   "amável" "ável"
```

This could be solved easily by

```
library(stringi)
stri_sub(rep(word, 6), from = -stri_length(df$suffix))
```

I bet you could reuse your `stringr` code just the same.

**### EDIT TO ADD ###**

I now understand what you mean. Definitely there's a strange behavior realated, most likely, to the special character `á`. See the example below:

```
df <- data.frame(suffix = c("Lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit","amet","consectetur","adipiscing", "elit","Donec","arcu")) 
df$len <- stri_length(df$suffix)
```

Then look at the strange behavior in the 7th element of the result:

```
stri_sub("amavel", from = -df$len)
##  [1] "mavel"  "mavel"  "mavel"  "vel"    "avel"   "amavel" "amavel" "avel"  
##  [9] "mavel"  "avel" 

# Compared to
stri_sub("amável", from = -df$len)
##  [1] "mável"  "mável"  "mável"  "vel"    "ável"   "amável" "mável"  "ável"  
##  [9] "mável"  "ável"
```

Weird enough, the result is corrected in the last case if `rep` is used:

```
stri_sub(rep("amável", 10), from = -df$len)
## [1] "mável"  "mável"  "mável"  "vel"    "ável"   "amável" "amável" "ável"  
## [9] "mável"  "ável"

# note how the 7th element is now correct.
```

So even though it's a bit hacky, **the solution provided above should work**.

I tried looking at the code of `stri_sub`, where it refers to `C_stri_sub`, but that was a dead end for me. Perhaps somebody more knowledgeable of `C` and/or string manipulation can come and lend a hand?

**### SECOND EDIT ###**

It seems to me the problem is with the repetition of the string *inside the call to `stri_sub`*. Look at this alternative code to the one you put in your edit:

```
set.seed(100)
a <- sample(1:10, 10000, replace = TRUE)
res <- stri_sub(rep("ábc", 10000), from = -a)
sum(ifelse(a > 3, 3, a) != stri_length(res))
## [1] 0
```

Comment: I don't think this solve the problem. I'll add a more simple reproducible example.

Comment: What's your expected output? My code produces the result I pasted on top of the answer, which is the one I would expect.

Comment: I know it solved. Look at the simple new example. Your solution does not work for bigger vectors. It makes no sense that your solution works too, since in documentation stringr says it recycles all arguments to the lenght of the longest one.